# How to parse an [object Object] returned by ajax and jquery that has a hashmap as a value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know this has been asked several times before but I can't seem to get the hang of it. I have a simple ajax call getting data that returns an [object Object] but I can't seem to parse it correctly.

Each object has a code, desc, and then a hashmap called productModel. All I want to do is get the value for the code and append that to the dropdown. But I keep either getting [object Object] or undefined.

A sample object from this rest api call would be:

```
{"code":"54","desc":"9384 TRUCK ","prodModels":{"29":{"code":"29","desc":"4839 TRUCK MOD"}}}
```

```
$(document).on("change", '#FM-productType-cbox', function(e) {
    var productTypeCode = $(this).val();
    var url = url;
    if(url != null){

        $.ajax({
            url : url.concat(productTypeCode),
            timeout : 2000,
            dataType : "json",
            statusCode : {

            },
            success: function(data) {

                var $el = $("#FM-productFamily-cbox");
                $el.empty(); // remove old options
                $el.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", '').text('Please Select'));
                $.each(data, function(value, key) {
                    $el.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value).text(key));
                });                                                     
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Debugging hint :  Within your `each` loop log `value `and `key` to console so you can see what you are working with

Comment: Yeah, currently working through that right now.

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` returns inside success method?

Comment: @charlietfl It looks like the key is just the value starting from 0 and the value is the code, desc, and prodModel object. I just need to figure out how to get the code and be able to set that to a variable now.

Comment: @palaѕн console.log(data) returns the entire hashmap for 54. However, I believe I may have figured it out.  console.log(value.code) gives me the code for each one which is exactly what I needed!

Comment: try like `console.log(data.prodModels['29'].code)` and see what does this print .

Comment: @Swati I actually got it working the way I want it now. I'll update the question shortly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed code and fully working.

```
function getProductFamily(){
    var productTypeCode = $("#FM-productType-cbox option:selected").val();
    var url = "<url>";
    var $pf = $("#FM-productFamily-cbox");
    var $pm = $("#FM-productModel-cbox");

    if(url != null){
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            timeout : 2000,
            dataType : "json",
            statusCode : {  },
            success: function(data) {
                $pf.empty(); 
                $pm.empty(); // remove old options
                $pf.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", '').text('Please Select'));
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    $pf.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value.code).text(value.code + " - " + value.desc)); 
                });                                                     
              }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: please don't put an answer in the question as an update, because it's harder for people to find it. It's fine to post an answer on your own question though. I've moved the content here for you, but if you want to make it an even better answer it would be good to include some explanation with it so that future readers know _why_ this is the answer to your question.

Comment: Alright, great. Thanks for the advice.